# Cursor movement in UITextView on iPad

Tags: ipad, cursor, uitextview

How to implement the move leftward like pressing the left button on the physical keyboard in iPad?

I can get the current cursor position, but I need to figure out a way to calculate the width of the current character and subtract that from the current x position.

Is there anyway to calculate the width of the current character? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to calculate the width of the current character if you want to move a cursor in UITextView.
UITextView has a property called selectedRange that gives the current position and selected range of the cursor in UITextView.
You just have to assign a new range value into your UITextView's selectedRange property.
For example,

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.selectedRange.location - 1, 0);
```